# How can I make that while thing are loading in the constructor it will image with a progressBar?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code in the constructor:

```
InitializeComponent();

            textBox3_text_valid = 0;
            label8.Visible = false;
            label8.Visible = false;
            Logger.exist();
            dt1 = DateTime.Now;
            label1.Text = dt1.ToLongTimeString();
            temperature_label = new Label();
            textMode_label = new Label();
            this.Controls.Add(textMode_label);
            this.Controls.Add(temperature_label);

            temperature_label.Location = new Point(260, 200);
            temperature_label.Height = 250;
            temperature_label.Width = 500;
            temperature_label.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            temperature_label.Font = new Font("Arial", 35, FontStyle.Bold);

            textMode_label.Location = new Point(350, 200);
            textMode_label.Height = 250;
            textMode_label.Width = 500;
            textMode_label.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            textMode_label.Font = new Font("Arial", 35, FontStyle.Bold);
            textMode_label.Text = " - הטמפרטורה כעת";

            path_log = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + @"\log";
            fullPath = path_log + log_file_name;

            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 100;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Start();
            textBox3.Text = Options_DB.Get_textBox3_time();
            computer = new Computer();
            computer.Open();
            computer.GPUEnabled = true;
```

The problem is that `computer.Open();` take about 3-5 seconds.
computer variable is part of the Computer class of OpenHardwareMonitor-LIB.dll

This `computer.Open` causes Open to add a CPU hardware device.

I don't think there is a way to make it work faster so instead how can I show some image on the screen with a `progressBar` that will move until everything is up in the constructor ?

I think it is called: SplashForm.

Comment: You should run that in a background thread after the form is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it is called a splash screen. There are numerous questions/answers on how to do this in WinForms. Here are a couple, but if you search for "splash form" or "splash screen" and winforms and InitializeComponent you'll find more:

[Is it possible to create a splash screen before InitializeComponent is called on Form Load of Winforms application?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/29219d02-2b35-4319-87e3-4309a4cc669b/is-it-possible-to-create-a-splash-screen-before-initializecomponent-is-called-on-form-load-of)

[Updating a Splash Screen with Loading Progress in a VB.Net WinForms Application](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/A_3671-Updating-a-Splash-Screen-with-Loading-Progress-in-a-VB-Net-WinForms-Application.html)

**ADDITION**

This one looks better explained:

[Creating a Splash Screen in .NET with a progress bar](http://crazorsharp.blogspot.com/2009/06/creating-splash-screen-in-net-with.html)